# Finding Area Of Triangle In Java

Tags: java

```
public class RightTriangle
{
    private double leg_1;
    private double leg_2;

    public RightTriangle ()
    {
        leg_1 = 1;
        leg_2 = 1;
    }

    public RightTriangle (double s1, double s2)
    {
        leg_1= s1 ;
        leg_2= s2 ;
    }

    public double findArea ()
    {
      double area= ((leg_1+leg_2)/2);
      return area;
    }

    public double findPerimeter ()
    {
          double s3Squared= Math.pow(leg_1,2) + Math.pow( leg_2,2);
          double s3= Math.sqrt(s3Squared);

          double perimeter=(leg_1 + leg_2 + s3);
          return perimeter;
    }

    public void dilate (double factor)
    {
    }

        RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle (3, 4);
        t1.findArea();

}
```

For my Java program, the constructor should construct a triangle by default with two legs with a length of one. The other constructor allows you to choose the length of the triangles two legs.

I'm trying to test my program's methods by running the "findArea" method with my t1 triangle object, however when I try to run the program I get a "identifier expeced after the token error with my my t1.findArea() code highlighted. Please help me fix this error.

Comment: Is it all the code you run? The object creation comes from a different class or stay in the class as it is?

Comment: This is all the code I run. The object creation comes from the same class.

Comment: you have code ***outside*** any method declaration, that is the reason for your error. Put the code in a method (possibly a *`main()`* method) and try it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a `main` class to get your program started. Also, this line:

```
t1.findArea();
```

needs to be placed inside a method. I propose you change the last two lines of code to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle (3, 4);
    t1.findArea();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a main method to make your class runnable.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle(3, 4);
        System.out.println(t1.findArea());
}
```

So the full code will be

```
public class RightTriangle {
    private double leg_1;
    private double leg_2;

    public RightTriangle() {
        leg_1 = 1;
        leg_2 = 1;
    }

    public RightTriangle(double s1, double s2) {
        leg_1 = s1;
        leg_2 = s2;
    }

    public double findArea() {
        double area = ((leg_1 + leg_2) / 2);
        return area;
    }

    public double findPerimeter() {
        double s3Squared = Math.pow(leg_1, 2) + Math.pow(leg_2, 2);
        double s3 = Math.sqrt(s3Squared);
        double perimeter = (leg_1 + leg_2 + s3);
        return perimeter;
    }

    public void dilate(double factor) {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle(3, 4);
        System.out.println(t1.findArea());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: I've appended the full code of the RightRectangle class.

Answer (score 1):

```
RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle (3, 4);
t1.findArea();
```

That needs to be in a method called through main

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RightTriangle t1 = new RightTriangle (3, 4);
    t1.findArea();
}
```